# Are apps "delivered by a door-to-door salesman" in any way, according to FTC rules?

Tags: united-states, internet

If a person buys an app on the Google Play store, is the person "buying from a door-to-door salesman" or not?

That is, the FTC has a mandatory 3-day "[Cooling-off Period for Sales Made at Home or Other Locations](https://www.ftc.gov/enforcement/rules/rulemaking-regulatory-reform-proceedings/cooling-period-sales-made-home-or-other)."

I'm asking because the buyer does not visit any physical location, but no salesman comes to the buyer's house.  Does the 3-day cooling-off period apply?

Comment: By ftc rules I am referring to the 3 days cool off rule .

Answer (score 5):

### No

Via the [FTC](https://www.consumer.ftc.gov/articles/0176-buyers-remorse-when-ftcs-cooling-rule-may-help) (emphasis added):

> The Cooling-Off Rule does not cover sales that are:
>
> ...
>
> - **made entirely online**, or by mail or telephone;